# My account staying logged when the browser closed

Tags: membership, logging

I want to logout with browser closing. Actually my account seems logged out in front-end but appears logged-in in back-end.

How can I logged out when I close browser?

Comment: You'll need to change the lifetime of the authentication cookies to 'session only', You might be able to do that with the auth_cookie_expiration hook, else you can override the function that creates the cookies since it's in pluggable.php.

Comment: I couldn't find it. where it is? I'm not pro of php, so I don't know how can I do it.

Comment: This isn't possible from WordPress/PHP/HTML/JS, to do it you would need to tell your browser to clear all cookies on close from the browser preferences

Comment: the question can close. I fixed it